# Pulling items from Allitems view using caml query

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two views. One is Dashboard view, and next one is AllItems View. Here, Dashboard is the Default View. But i have to pull items from Allitems view using CAML Query. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty basic.

Assuming you have a `SPList` object, you just specify the `View` property:

```
SPList list = website.Lists["Listname"];
SPView queryView = list.View["AllItems"];

queryView.Query = " ... " 
queryView.Update();
```

There are already a lot of resources available convering this:

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39474/filtering-items-in-a-view-using-a-caml-query
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42612/how-to-set-caml-query-for-special-view
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434064(v=office.14).aspx